# Kubernetes - Container Knowing about Node it's scheduled to

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

I'm trying to figure out a way that a container or pod can know some specific information about the node that it's being scheduled to. For example, my container might have to know if a GPU is present or not on that node in order to decide whether or not to enable GPU acceleration. Another example would be knowing the $DISPLAY variable of the node to know what X server to output graphics to.

What's the best approach to this?

Thanks

Update: If I could get the node-name from within the container, I could do a lookup against an external service to get the information I need. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand the `$DISPLAY` use case: you've tagged this for GKE, so your pods will be running somewhere in the cloud, in a data center outside your control, probably with no display hardware attached to them at all.  If you tried to run an interactive X application, where would you want its display to appear?  (Where could it?)

Comment: I'm running both on in-house nodes as well as cloud-based nodes. Take for example the following use-case: I have a mixture of trusted in-house nodes that all have different setups and pods scheduled to these 'trusted' nodes will display some information in a X control-panel on the node. I have a third-party application that I cannot modify with teh requirement to output a gui to the node it's running on. Now each node has its own setup, some are running on display :0 others on :10 and yet others on other unknown displays. I need some way to communicate which DISPLAY is the active one

Answer (score 2):

OP Here. I've found a somewhat decent way of accomplishing this.

On setting the node up with my cluster i can install a script to source environment variables to a file then volume-mount that file into the container.

Alterntively I could also store config for each ndoe in a separate service and inject the nodeName to lookup properties of a specific node as follows:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables

Then based on the name, my container can look-up via service or config map a mapping of nodeName to whatever information I need form the node. All I have to do is keep this service/config map up-to-date with the node's information.

Comment: You can query node specs from the K8s API server.

Answer (score 0):

[Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) were designed for that.

Comment: My understanding of taints and tolerations is that they allow certain pods to be scheduled to certain nodes (or more likely to be). I would like my pod to run on all nodes but have some information about the underlying node. I can't afford to tell my pod to only run on nodes with display variable of :10